# Facing difficulties with amazon url signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-signature

I am following each step to create a signature for my url requests to amazon(or at least that's what I think) but it doesn't work.

I am trying to sign an example from the amazon's page( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

I have downloaded the s3-sigtester, a javascript file that creates the signatures. The string that I am signing is:

```
GET \necs.amazonaws.co.uk \n/onca/xml \nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJOCH6NNDJFTB4LYA&Actor=Johnny%20Depp&AssociateTag=memagio-21&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews%2CVariations&SearchIndex=DVD&Service=AWSECommerceService&Sort=salesrank&Timestamp=2014-10-19T21%3A21%3A55Z&Version=2009-01-01
```

The string above is the result from the sigtester. I am feeding it in hex. I get a signature and then, I am trying to access the following url, in order to get the xml values:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.co.uk/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJOCH6NNDJFTB4LYA
&Actor=Johnny%20Depp&AssociateTag=memagio-21&Operation=ItemSe
arch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews%2CV
ariations&SearchIndex=DVD&Service=AWSECommerceService&Signature=vZK%2BhDqtcV1CoTf6%2FN1ohR3Da5M%3D&Sort=salesrank&Ti
mestamp=2014-10-19T21%3A21%3A55Z&Version=2009-01-01
```

The AWASCcessKeyId and signature key are the AWS keys that I have created. However, I get an error that the signatures do not match. I think that I am following all the steps and I really don't know what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The string that I am signing is:

```
GET \necs.amazonaws.co.uk \n/onca/xml \nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJOCH6NNDJFTB4LYA&Actor=Johnn
```

I assume `\n` denotes a newline character (Unicode `000A`).  The problem is that there should not be spaces before the newlines - it needs to be `GET\necs.amazonaws.co.uk\n...`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still get the same error message.